# R - Change column names of a matrix on the basis of their mapping with other values

Tags: r, matrix

I'm new to R and I'm going to use it in my research activity :)

The question is:

- I have a matrix

  gene.names.as.matrix

> ```
> head(gene.names.as.matrix)
>
>      EIF4E ULK3... RPS6 EIF4EBP1 STRADA CAB39 BRAF 
> [1,]     0       0    0        0      0     0    0    
> [2,]     0       0    0        0      0     0    0    
> [3,]     0       0    0        0      0     0    0    
> [4,]     0       0    0        0      0     0    0    
> [5,]     0       0    0        0      0     0    0    
> [6,]     0       0    0        0      0     0    0
> ```

with many rows and other columns that are not displayed here for brevity.

- I have another matrix

  gene.id.map

> ```
> head(gene.id.map)
>
>       gene.symbol gene.id
> 1977  "EIF4E"     "1977" 
> 25989 "ULK3..."   "25989"
> 6194  "RPS6"      "6194" 
> 1978  "EIF4EBP1"  "1978" 
> 92335 "STRADA"    "92335"
> 51719 "CAB39"     "51719"
> ```

- I want to change the column names of

  gene.names.as.matrix

on the basis of the values present in the matrix

```
gene.id.map
```

Thus, the result matrix should be something like:

```
     1977 25989 6194 [...]
[1,]     0       0    0     
[2,]     0       0    0     
[3,]     0       0    0 
[...]
```

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't use numbers as column names

Comment: And what should I use?

Comment: Names, for example `'gene.id'` instead of `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
  colnames(gene.names.as.matrix)[match(gene.id.map[,1], colnames(gene.names.as.matrix))] <- genes.id.map[,2][match(gene.id.map[,1], colnames(gene.names.as.matrix))]

 gene.names.as.matrix
 #      1977 25989  6194  1978 92335 51719 BRAF
 #[1,]     0     0     0     0     0     0    0
 #[2,]     0     0     0     0     0     0    0
 #[3,]     0     0     0     0     0     0    0
 #[4,]     0     0     0     0     0     0    0
 #[5,]     0     0     0     0     0     0    0
 #[6,]     0     0     0     0     0     0    0
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. There is a little syntax error on the name of the matrix but it's just a typo ;)

Comment: @alevax Glad to know it works.  I copied the example as you showed in the post.  It would be better to show `dput(head(data,10))` output in the future to get the structure correctly.